# Django hide password fields on user creation form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom user model and a form that allows admins to add users without having to go to the admin section. I want hide the password fields and set the password to a random generated string. Then send an email to the new user with a link to reset their password.

So far I haven't been able to figure out the first part - hiding the password fields.

The form.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class AddCompanyEmployeeForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('email', 'full_name', 'age')
```

the view:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView
from django.urls.base import reverse
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, AddCompanyEmployeeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

class AddCompanyEmployee(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'manage/add_employee.html'
    form_class = AddCompanyEmployeeForm
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('directory')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('userprofile_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.userprofile.pk})
```

The custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_type = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1)
    employee_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
```

I have tried a number of approaches including changing the form to

```
class AddCompanyEmployeeForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'full_name', 'age')
```

So far the password fields continue to be visible regardless of what I try. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `exclude` to hide password fields in Meta class and share your `CustomUser` model.

Comment: I added the CustomUser model above.

Comment: Use `exclude=['password']` in Meta class to hide that field.

Comment: I just tried adding ```exclude=['password']``` to the meta class. I am still seeing the password fields.

Comment: You should't have the passwords stored as plaintext anyway - they should be hashes. If you can see the "real" password in the admin you've set it wrong.

Comment: I think they are stored as hashes. I just think the users should create their own. I could still send the link to the user to reset their password. However, it could confuse/concern the admins if they have to enter a password for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently password1 and password2 fields are defined in form directly when using UserCreationForm, not in the model. So exclude and fields will have no effect on them.

You have to make the form with ModelForm or Form.

Answer (score 0):

you should be override UserCreationForm like this...

## User Signup

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email',]
        exclude = ['password1','password1',]
```

then after you can set your string password like this in (views.py)

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            fm = form.save(commit=False)
            fm.password = make_password('your_rendom_string')
            fm.save()
            messages.success(request,f'{username} Successfully Registred')
            form = UserCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()
        context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you Mahammadhusain. it looks like this should work. However, the password fields still show up on the form. I did set the model to CustomUser rather than User though since I'm using a CustomUser model.

Comment: you want to show password field like this ⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪ ??

Comment: Ideally there would be no password field visible on the form.